# Using the Perl module JSON to create a JSON object

Tags: jquery, perl, json

I'm having a killer time trying to create a JSON object to return to a jQuery request.

I'm trying to use the [jQuery chained select module](http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/)

and I'm trying to create the JSDN object using Perl's [JSON module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON).

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong or how I can even debug it, about the best I can do is get a JS dialog box coming up with "A unknown error....".

This is all I was trying to do to create the JSON object, I thought this would be all that is needed, but it's not. Any ideas?

TIA

```
use JSON;
my %data = (1 => 'val1',
            2 => 'val2',
            3 => 'val3',
           );
my $json_text = to_json(\%data);
print $json_text;
```

Comment: So what of the answers suggested was the correct one? With this question there is much guessing involved. Maybe add more details.

Answer (score 5):

Running the script gives:

```
{"1":"val1","3":"val3","2":"val2"}
```

… which is the expected output.

The problem almost certainly lies with whatever code you are using to get the JSON from your server to the client.

Comment: I'm just printing it out - I thought that was all that was needed?  "print $json_text"

Comment: @Chris: The code snippet you provided in the question above is correct, and works properly. Try it again yourself in a standalone script and see.  (So it must be something else in your script that is wrong.)

Comment: Where are you printing it to? What does the output look like?

Answer (score 1):

Have the javascript output the response text before processing to a textarea so you can see if there's something failing in transport.  Also, you're going to want to put something in front of the data, like "myVar= " so that the data is assigned to something on the other end.

Comment: Thanks Woolstar, I'll try to figure out how to do that (I know nothing about JQuery)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you already figured it out your issue, and if you were wondering why it wasn't working is because the to_json method is not exported from JSON.pm in the older versions of the JSON module. The latest version on CPAN (2.0) exports to_json into your namespace but versions ~1.5 don't and require the JSON::. Many repos still carry this older version, and if you are running on CentOS ~5.3 or an older version of Fedora Core you will have the older JSON.pm.